# add yarn workspace to other workspace as dependecy

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo

I want to setup a yarn workspace monorepo structure to my project, below is the basic structure.

```
Main
   - packages
       - Auth
           - package.json
       - Site1
           - package.json
       - Site2
           - package.json
   - package.json
```

```
/* Main/package.json */
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "Main",
    "workspaces": ["./packages/*"]
}
```

I want to add the `@Main/Auth` packages dependency to `@Main/Site1` and `@Main/Site2`. I have tried this

```
yarn workspace Site1 add Auth
```

It's giving the error:
`An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@Main/Auth: Not found".`

PS: I have just added `@Main` as a prefix to make this less common.

Comment: What is in your `Site1/package.json` right now?

Comment: inside dependencies, imported `@Main/Auth: 1.0.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from looking at the [Yarn docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), you don't issue a `yarn` command or anything, you just manually build the `package.json` files by hand.

So, inside `Site/package.json` you would put something like:

```
{
  "name": "@Main/Site1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@Main/Auth": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```